# Separating socket.io event logic into module

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have seen a couple of questions referencing this issue however was not able to get this working.

I have an app that is running express for both API routes as well as socket real time app.

I would like to keep my server.js file "clean" and have all the socket related events in a separate file. I also want to be able to fire an event from within my route files.

My server.js loks like this:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv/config');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
var http = require('http');
const _ = require('lodash');
const path = require('path');
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');


var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
var {authenticate} = require('./middleware/authenticate');
var {socketEvents} = require('./middleware/socketEvents')(io);
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
  multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();

var app = express()
var serv = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = socketIO.listen(serv)


var PORT = process.env.PORT || '80';
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multipartyMiddleware);
app.use(express.static(publicPath));


serv.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Started on port: ' + PORT);
});

module.exports = {
  app
};
```

I would like to have a socketEvents.js file that includes:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New user connected');

//all socket events here

});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You may test the following pattern:

server.js

```
'use strict';
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const io_logic = require('./socketEvents')(io);
console.log('socket.io server started at port 3000');
```

socketEvents.js

```
function socket_events (io) {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
          console.log('a client has connected');
    });
}
module.exports = socket_events;
```

Comment: I want to run both the sockets server as well as the Express API routes over port 80. IN your sample code the sockets server is running over port 3000. How can I run both over same port. If I remove the port from const io = require('socket.io')(3000); I get an error when running " TypeError: io.on is not a function"  thanks

Comment: OK- so I did manage to get both servers running however now my client is complaining that it can't find the socket.io.js file - does the path move when I load from another location? How can I determine the correct path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

- This is how you can separate `Express logic` and `Socket.io logic` in separate modules.

```js
// index.js file, entry file for your express server

import * as http from "http";
import app, { express } from "./app";
import initializeSocket from "./socket";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const httpPort = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// create express http server
const expressHttpServer = http.createServer(app);

initializeSocket(expressHttpServer);

expressHttpServer.listen(httpPort, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at ${httpPort} ⚡`);
});

export default express;
```

```js
// app.js file, for express logic

import * as express from "express";
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

const app = express.default();
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Hello from the TypeScript world!</h1>");
});

export { express };
export default app;
```

```js
// socket.js file, for socket.io logics

const socket = require("socket.io");

function initializeSocket(httpServer) {
 io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("connection", socket.id);
 });
}

export default initializeSocket;
```

- Hope I answered your question.